# how to test/use Zend Framework + Zend Server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have installed Zend Framework + Zend Server on my computer. I am using win 7.
But how could i use/test it? eg. how could i run below script to do a test?

```
<?php
$date=new Zend_Date();
echo $date; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

how deploy with php application

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/getting-started/hello-world-sample#behind-the-code

http://www.zend.com/products/server/faq#faqD2

Answer (score 0):

you installed in zend server and your php file copy and paste C://zend server/www (or)root
   then open the browser type it localhost
   then type file in url

Comment: The file structure is:
Zend
--ZendServer
----bin
----data
----doc
----etc
----gui
----lib
----logs
----share
----tmp
----UserServer

No such folder www/root

Answer (score 0):

Paste your test file in this location- User_Home_Dir/zend/Apache2/htdocs/